# regular expression to pull words beginning with @

Tags: vb.net, regular-language

Trying to parse an SQL string and pull out the parameters.

Ex:  "select * from table where [Year] between @Yr1 and @Yr2"

I want to pull out "@Yr1" and "@Yr2"

I have tried many patterns, but none has worked, such as:

```
matches = Regex.Matches(sSQL, "\b@\w*\b")
```

and

```
matches = Regex.Matches(sSQL, "\b\@\w*\b")
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to put a word boundary *after* the @, rather than before.  Maybe this:

> \w(@[A-Z0-9a-z]+)

or

> \w(@[^\s]+)

Answer (score 1):

I would have gone with

```
/^|\s(@\w+)\s|$/
```

or if you didn't want to include the @

```
/^|\s@(\w+)\s|$/
```

though I also like joel's above, so maybe one of these

```
/^|\s(@[^\s]+)\s|$/
/^|\s@([^\s]+)\s|$/
```